# What would it feel like if the entire Earth could fit into the palm of your hand?

Tags: planets, earth

You know the song "He has got the whole world in his hands"? Well, I was thinking the other day, if some being was theoretically big enough to fit the entire world in his hands, what would that be like? Would Earth's gravity make this being's hand be pulled into the Earth? What affects would it have on life on Earth (besides being crushed)? Could you throw Earth? I have been wondering this for a while and am very interested in the answer.

Comment: Giant space titan would be so far outside possible physics to function that what ever the author wants can happen.

Comment: This question reminds me of a question once posed by popular science writer Martin Gardner.  He asked, if you could shrink the earth to the size of a billiard ball, and then blot it dry with a towel, would you be able to feel the ocean basins and the mountain ranges.  Sadly, I can't find any online references to the question.  His answer was interesting to me:  he said the earth at such a size would actually be *smoother* than a billiard ball.

Comment: @CharlesBurge The Earth _is_ smoother than a cue ball. http://www.curiouser.co.uk/facts/smooth_earth.htm

Answer (score 5):

There are really two options for what this would be like, depending on whether physics has mostly been thrown out the window or not:

**Pretty much ignoring all the non-fun physics:** According to [this Skeptics StackExchange](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10763/is-earth-as-smooth-as-a-billiard-ball/10772), the earth is as smooth as pretty fine sandpaper, so it would 'feel' like holding a rough, mostly wet ball of rock. Since you're more massive than the Earth, and thus have more gravity, the atmosphere and all the water would quickly leave the Earth and [slosh around on the surface of your hands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8TssbmY-GM). Obviously, this would be bad for the Earth because people like having air and water. Earth is moving fast around the sun, but if you're already moving fast enough to hold it, then you could definitely throw it since the only thing keeping it around the sun is gravity which you shouldn't have a problem overcoming.

**More realistic answer**: Assuming that you somehow handwaved physics on yourself in order to be this large, but not anything else, then really a few things could happen:

-If you are much more massive than the Earth, i.e. have more mass and thus more gravitational pull, [the Earth would be ripped apart by you just being near it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit). The chunks of (mostly)molten rock and iron would then fall towards your stomach(center of mass) where it would collect in a slowly pooling pile that slowly spreads out around the middle of your body. Obviously, this would be bad for anyone on the Earth.

-If the Earth is much more massive than you, i.e. you're big but very light, then *you* would be pulled apart by the Earth, again due to the effects of passing the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit). Now *your* molten chunks get to fall towards the center of Earth's mass! Again, pretty bad for anyone on the Earth(which technically includes you now).

-If you and the Earth are similarly massive, then you would both be deformed and pulled apart as you fall towards eachother's center of mass. Again, not the best situation for life on Earth.

Comment: I love this answer so much. +1 for physics!

Answer (score 3):

It would probably crumble into mud and rocks.

Then you would burn your hand *really* bad.

Oh, and the moon might bump you in the head.

Answer (score 0):

1. Would Earth's gravity make this being's hand be pulled into the Earth?
   More like Earth will be pulled towards the titan (since he is more massive)
2. What affects would it have on life on Earth (besides being crushed)?
   Areas that are not crushed will first experience strong wind from the hand coming down, and then massive earthquakes from the squeeze of the giant's hand.
3. Could you throw Earth?
   Yes he could. Acceleration will definitely blow everybody off the earth, or kill them.

Comment: Not sure about the last point. Since everyone would be accelerated at the same rate as the planet itself, they won't get blown off; knocked down perhaps, but not blown off.  Same with getting killed: the earth is under constant acceleration, as it isn't travelling in a straight line, but we only really feel the effect of gravity, as the earth's relative size absorbs most of the force acting on it.